# Word or phrase for "not being into something that much as the other person thinks"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase used for describing something that one does not want to do as much as another person thinks? For example,

> I'm not ______ to do that as much as you think!

Edit: Thanks for all the answers and the editing of my original question :)

At first I did not mention this but it can give a clue, or there may just not be a word for what I am trying to say. I am actually looking for a word with a very specific meaning in my native language. It is said when someone senses that the other person seems to be looking down on him/her, although not openly. So this person needs to remind that he/she has the dignity for not desiring the thing the other person thinks he/she desires.

Comment: "*I'd rather not.*"

Answer (score 1):

In British English there is a word that fits this quite well.

Keen - To show an interest in or be enthusiastic about something. Much like being into something.

In this situation I would say:
"I'm not too keen on that." - Meaning that I'm not interested or excited about it.

You could also say "really not keen" if you want to be more forceful.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keen)

Comment: add a citation to KEEN ... that is a link to a reputable source supporting the answer.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keen

Comment: i will do this for you. take the tutorials for your future use.

Comment: or "quite so keen"since OP asked for a comparative in the title.

Answer (score 0):

- "I'm not really that much into it"
- or a rather unpolite version to express ones unwillingness to do something: "I can't be bothered"

I'm afraid I can't think of any phrase that matches exactly what you want: expressing that the inclination is much less than the other person thinks.

Answer (score 0):

I **deign** not participate in such as you ask!

> Definition of deign, intransitive verb: to condescend reluctantly and
>   with a strong sense of the affront to one's superiority that is
>   involved : stoop
>
> ```
> would *not even deign* to talk to him
>
> One iconoclastic architect, for example, doesn't deign to speak of
> ```
>
> bathrooms. —Carol Vogel
>
> transitive verb : to condescend to give or offer
>
> ```
> never so much as deigning a glance —George Meredith  [Merriam][1]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not ***inclined*** to do that as much as you think!

ODO:

> **[incline](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incline)**
>   *VERB*
>
> 1 (usually *be inclined to/towards/to do something*) Be favourably
>   disposed towards or willing to do something.
>
> ‘Even children seem to be more inclined towards indoor activities and
>   television rather than playing outdoors.’

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that is more colloquial in flavour:

[*down to do something*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+down+to+(do+something)).

I could only find The Free Dictionary as a verifiable source for the same. It defines the idiom as:

**be down to (do something)**

To be ready, willing, or eager to do something.

*I'm down to play a quick game of soccer if you are.*

*I am so down to see that movie tonight, I've been waiting for it to come out for months!*

*A: "You want in?" B: "Yeah, I'm down."*